# Use local storage to remember jQuery modal popups when minimized, even if page is reloaded or changed

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, popup, minimize

thank you in advance and sorry for my bad english. I'm not a javascript developer and therefore it's difficult, to me, to improve all alone the code that I have on my website, so any specific help is very welcome.

Inside the file called footer.inc.php that - of course - is common to all pages, I have a script that open the url inside the main page as modal popups. I can close them or reduce them.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function modalWindow(name, title, url, width, height) {
        // per width ed height imposto dei valori di default così non occorre specificarli in ogni occasione
        width = typeof width === 'undefined' ? 800 : width;
        height = typeof height === 'undefined' ? 600 : height;

        // verifichiamo se nel body non esiste il sorgente per la dialog
        if (top.$('#dialog-'+name).length == 0) {

            // in questo caso lo creiamo:
            top.$('body').append('<div id="dialog-' +name+ '" title="' +title+ '" style="padding:0;"><iframe src="' + url + '" frameborder="no" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;" scrolling="yes"></div>');

        } else {

            // se il sorgente invece esiste già assegnamo la nuova url all´iframe:
             top.$('#dialog-' +name).attr('title', title);
             top.$('#dialog-' +name+ ' iframe').attr('src', url);
        }

        // Ok, adesso siamo pronti per lanciare la modale!
       top.$('#dialog-' +name).dialog({width: width, height: height});
        top.$('#dialog-' +name).dialog({width: width, height: height}).dialogExtend({"minimizable" : true}).dialog({ position: { my: "center", at: "center+20px", of: target } });
        $("#dialog").dialog({ position: { my: "center", at: "top+30%", of: window } });
    }
</script>
```

*dialogExtend({"minimizable" : true})* allows me to minimize the popup windows, but if I refresh or change the page, the popups will be lost.

Can I ask you how to change and improve the code above so that the opened modal popups won't be lost, even if I change or reload the page?

I got and answer but, since I don't know javascript well enough, I cannot improve the code by myself.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You have a function that you call with few parameters. I would save those parameters in localStorage, then when reloading the page I would read the content of LS and call the function.

```
var modals = localStorage.getItem('modals');

if (modals) {
   modals = JSON.parse(modals);
} else {
   modals = [];
}

modals.forEach(args => {
   modalWindow(...args);
});

function modalWindow(name, title, url, width, height) {
   ...
   modals.push([name, title, url, width, height]);
   localStorage.setItem('modals', JSON.stringify(modals));
}
```

You probably also want to remove the modal from the list when you close it. You can come up with a better data structure that will allow you to do that.

Comment: jcubic thank you
unfortunatelly, I'm not that inside jscript code... 

I'm trying to understand how to improve your answer. But really thank you for helping.

Comment: @ValentinaFurnò sorry I have no idea what you mean. This is the answer, I don't think you will find anything else.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my first language. I don't know javascript well enough to use your answer and edit my code to do what I need it to do.

It's absolutely not your fault! On the contrary, thank you for the help!